# iOS: autolayout move view from left to top right

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have 3 views and I wish to handle their layouts using autolayout constraints.
Portrait is like this:

[image]

and landscape should be as follows:

[image]

How do I do this using autolayout? I tried adding constraints, but the 3rd view(in green color), doesn't move up. It moves on the right side though.

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve it?

Comment: For the, smaller two views set top and left margin constraints with fixed values and for the bigger one, set the bottom and right margin constraints with fixed values.

Comment: I want to add constraints using autolayout in xib- i.e. through Editor menu-> Pin etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be easily done using **Size Classes** , take a look at apple doc [Size Classes design help](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436)

This feature available only in xCode 6 [New Features in xCode 6](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_6_0.html).

[image: Constraints in w**Any** h**Any** layout]

[image: Constraints in w**Any** h**Compact** layout]

Keep the same Constraints for other layouts.

Note that Gray coloured constraints are not installed for present layout.

You can find the sample in the link [DownLoad Sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fdxqwj2uurh0jki/SizeClass.zip)

Comment: but isn't it easily possible through autolayout?

Comment: This is the easiest way(for any iOS device of any length one viewController). Please go through the docs to understand what it does.

Comment: I studied the doc, size class is used to define universal xib layout for all devices- iPhone+iPad. But how do I solve the layout issue that is given in my question? Using size classes and autolayout- I added leading spaces to above 2 views(to align them on left), then I added trailing space to the third view and ran the app- the app screen showed no view. On removing the constraint for the third view(last added constraint), the app screen showed all 3 views in default manner.

Comment: You should try in Xcode 6, select a constraint and in the attribute inspector you can choose where it can be installed(You can add or remove constraint for a particular layout there). I think its better to practice some samples to understand what it is.

Comment: Nice work! can you share this sample code project link so that I can study it. By this image I am not getting which constraint is applied to which view. :)